express-jwt function in node js
I have the below code
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('express-jwt');

const app = express();

// Middleware to authenticate requests using JWT
app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'your-secret-key'
}).unless({
  path: ['/login']
}));

// Example route that requires authentication
app.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
  // If the request reaches here, it means it's authenticated`
  res.send('You are authenticated!');
});

// Example route for logging in and obtaining JWT token
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // Logic to authenticate user and generate JWT token
  // Once authenticated, send back JWT token
  const token = jwt.sign({
    username: 'exampleUser'
  }, 'your-secret-key');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});

I'm getting this error.

TypeError: jwt is not a function

I tried chatGPT and Gemeni but I am not able to solve the problem.

The problem with the way you import jwt: const jwt = require('express-jwt'); 
The correct way according to readme:
const express = require('express');
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require('express-jwt');

const app = express();

// Middleware to authenticate requests using JWT
app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'your-secret-key'
}).unless({
  path: ['/login']
}));

// the rest of the code...

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});


with version greater than 7 use this and docs-link
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");

